# calling function in ScrollView onscroll property

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an animated view which I want to execute more than one event in that `onScroll` property. now the the `onScroll` is this:

```
onScroll={
                    Animated.event(
                    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scroll } } }],
                    { useNativeDriver: true },
                )
```

and I want to do some thing more than `Animeted.event()` in that. so I took it inside a function like this:

```
animatedEv(){
    Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scroll } } }],
        { useNativeDriver: true },
    )
        //----and maybe some thing more here 
}
```

and I called what you see above in the `onScroll`:

```
onScroll={()=>
                  this.animatedEv
                }
```

but despite the success function call, the animated doesn't work properly in these new style....even I tried this:

```
onScroll={
            ()=>{this.animatedEv() } 
  }
```

in both style there is no error but the animated is not working properly ):

**Edit:**
this is my scroll which is a variable in top of my component:

```
 scroll = new Animated.Value(0);
```

Comment: is there any solution to above problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
onScroll={
    Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scroll } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true },
)}
```

it is similar than

```
onScroll={(scrollEvent) => {
    Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scroll } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true },
))(scrollEvent)
}}
```

so if you want to get your code out of this try

```
animatedEv = (event) => {
    Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scroll } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true },
    ))(event)
    //other stuff
};
...
onScroll={this.animatedEv}
```

EDIT: error on first answer